# C# - Launch method in MdiParent when one specific MdiChild is closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm actually building a program at school in .net. This is the first time I'm using it and I've got a question.

I got a `MdiParent` form which has two `MdiChildren` : a `config` form, and an articles list form. When you fill the `config` form, the articles list should appear.

I'm actually using this method in the `MdiParent` :

```
private void MotherMdi_MdiChildActivate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ...;
}
```

But I need to deal with multiple variables because this method is fired every time a `mdichild` is open or closed ...

Is there a way to call a specific method only when One `MdiChild` is closed ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event `FormClosing` is raised every time a windows form is closed. You can handle that event and do processing that you need to do when a form is closing.

In the parent form:

```
private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
            childForm.childFormClosed += childForm_childFormClosed;
        }

        void childForm_childFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle processing here
        }
```

In the child form:

```
public event EventHandler<FormClosingEventArgs> childFormClosed;

        private void ChildForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (childFormClosed != null)
            {
                childFormClosed(sender, e);
            }
        }
```

You may want to use `FormClosed` if that is what you need.

You can also use your own inherited class if you want to pass more information than what `FormClosingEventArgs` would do.

Comment: It's already done in the `MdiChild` config form, I've got specific processing in that function, but I also need to check that in the `MdiParent` to launch another `MdiChild`.